# Spring Boot Integration Test case and check if a method is called

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I need to write an Integration Test case . In the whole flow i do have a bean class which has a method. I want to write a test case case to check if that method was called in the test or not.
How can i do that ? Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the appropriate methods in Mockito

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.atLeast;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

verify(mockObject, atLeast(2)).someMethod("was called at least twice");
verify(mockObject, times(1)).someMethod("was called exactly one time");
```